# Issue with car rev'ing and brake!

Tags: engine, vw, polo

I have 04 VW Polo, it's a bit a complicated for me to explain as I have limited knowledge of car terminology, and this issue happens frequently but not constantly. 
So, issue number 1 is while I may be driving, The accelerator pedal suddenly becomes very loose and if I press it all the way, the car won't speed up at all. This is usually at higher speeds only, such as 100 Km/hr.

Issue number 2 happens frequently as well and it is while I may be driving in traffic at lower speeds, the car revs up to 2000 rpm and then ''it feels'' to suddenly brakes and jerks once to slow it down. this happens every time I try to rev past 2000 rpm. If I move my foot of off the accelerator pedal, eng just dies. turning it back on fixes the issue for a little while and then comes back again.

I took the car to a mechanic and he said, fuel pump need be changed, however, looking at the issue, I don't see why the fuel pump will affect the car in this manner. Tried other mechanics and each had different answers. I have been researching this for the last 2 weeks and I have not found anyone who had a similar issue. Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds almost like the throttle position sensor is having an issue. You could possibly test it (at least most you can) by putting a multimeter on resistance, connecting the leads onto the TPS output, then sweeping the throttle completely through it's range. You should have a continuous sweep across the entire range (smooth resistance change) without any jumping along the sweep. Just a thought.

Comment: I'd start with the TPS as Paulster2 suggested. After that, you'd probably want to start looking at the rest of the throttle system and then transmission. Depending on how everything is configured in your car, there could also be problems with the computer(s). Either way, just take it one step at a time, keep updating your question with new answers, and we'll all help to the best of our ability. :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I will start with throttle system first thing tomorrow morning and will figure it out eventually :)

Comment: I tried to do it myself but couldn't, took it to a garage, the mechanic said that the TPS is giving a good signal and he also cleaned it as well. Also, he has changed the fuel pump as it was fairly old. The car still shows the same issue still! The car is still in the garage as they said, they will check everything again.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't give much information on the engine type size if turbo or not...if its the turbo model sounds like the pressure pipe is loose or needs to be replaced...and yes i have known a problem just as you describe and that was the problem ..if you can give more information it would help me help you

Comment: It is a 1.2 hatchback, it has no turbo at all, just a normal 5-door car, I'm still new to car stuff so don't know much myself :(

Answer (score -1):

Could be the fuel pump. When you press the pedal thats when the throttle opens up and the fuel pump should supply the fuel according to the pedal, more fuel in less pedal would make the engine stop, more pedal in less fuel will make the engine stop as well. Could also be the fuel lines.